# Joint Denial Equivalents

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to calculate $(p\land q)\rightarrow (p \vee q)$ using just joint denial  $\def\jd{\downarrow}\jd$. I'm not sure if I've done it right... any help would be greatly appreciated!

My workings:
\begin{align*}
  (p \land q) \to (p \lor q)
  &\equiv (\neg p \jd \neg q) \to \neg (p \jd q)\\
  &\equiv \bigl((p \jd p) \jd (q \jd q)\bigr) \to \bigl((p\jd q)\jd (p\jd q)\bigr)\\
  &\equiv \neg \bigl((p \jd p) \jd (q \jd q)\bigr) \lor \bigl((p\jd q)\jd (p\jd q)\bigr)\\
  &\equiv \bigl((p \jd p) \jd (q \jd q)\bigr)\jd \bigl((p \jd p) \jd (q \jd q)\bigr) \lor \bigl((p\jd q)\jd (p\jd q)\bigr)\\
 &\equiv \neg \Bigl(\bigl((p \jd p) \jd (q \jd q)\bigr)\jd \bigl((p \jd p) \jd (q \jd q)\bigr) \jd \bigl((p\jd q)\jd (p\jd q)\bigr)\Bigr)\\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havent finished, there is still a $\neg$ in your term if $\neg t$ is your last term, you have to replace it with $t \downarrow t$, giving 
$$ \def\jd{\downarrow}\Bigl(\bigl((p \jd p) \jd (q \jd q)\bigr)\jd \bigl((p \jd p) \jd (q \jd q)\bigr) \jd \bigl((p\jd q)\jd (p\jd q)\bigr)\Bigr) \jd \Bigl(\bigl((p \jd p) \jd (q \jd q)\bigr)\jd \bigl((p \jd p) \jd (q \jd q)\bigr) \jd \bigl((p\jd q)\jd (p\jd q)\bigr)\Bigr) $$

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help!